# Populate variables with strings from within a string

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I have tried various PHP `str_*` functions, but can't find the right combination of replace, `explode()`, etc. to do what I need.

I want to grab some specific text that will be in a string -ex below:

> Terms of Service ID: **#928374** (Val: $**2.50**, Add'l fee: **10.25**%)

Note the string pieces in bold.  I need to grab them from that main string.  These bolded values of course change several times per user, which is really throwing me off.  The non-bolded text is consistent/constant.

Does anyone know if what I am attempting- can be accomplished? If so, could you please provide some guidance/insight?  Would be much appreciated.

Comment: explode on space, then you just loop and check for #... , $... and ...%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that most of the values are static, you can replace (most of the) static values from the string and explode on spaces. Then you're left with the three values (with a comma on the values, which you can trim away).

```
$replace = array("Terms of Service ID: #", "(Val: $", "Add'l fee: ", "%)");
$string = "Terms of Service ID: #928374 (Val: $2.50, Add'l fee: 10.25%)";

$result = str_replace($replace, "", $string);  // Replace static strings
$pieces = explode(" ", $result);               // Explode on spaces, get pieces
$pieces[1] = rtrim($pieces[1], ",");           // Trim away the trailing comma

$id = $pieces[0];
$value = $pieces[1];
$fee_percent = $pieces[2];
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/MYis8)

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a regular expression for this:

```
$str = "Terms of Service ID: #928374 (Val: $2.50, Add'l fee: 10.25%)";
$pattern = '/Terms of Service ID: (#[0-9]+) \(Val: (\$[0-9\.]+), Add\'l fee: ([0-9\.]+%)\)/';
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
```

Then it's just a matter of accessing the captured values in the `$matches` array in indexes 1, 2, and 3.

---

**Edit**

Here is a more compact regular expression which should be more resistant to formatting changes and excludes the `$` and `%` characters from the results:

```
$str = 'Terms of Service ID: #928374 (Val: $2.50, Add\'l fee: 10.25%)';
$pattern = '/(#[0-9]+)[^\$]+\$([0-9\.]+)[^0-9]+([0-9\.]+)%/';
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
```

Output for this specific example is:

```
$matches = array(
    "#928374 (Val: $2.50, Add'l fee: 10.25%",  //matched from the entire regular expression
    "#928374",  //first capture group
    "2.50",     //second capture group
    "10.25"     //third capture group
);
```

Comment: I like this version, but just couldn't get it to work quickly.  When I have a chance, I would like to play with it more to see what I am missing.  Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: It could be that I got the capture groups slightly wrong. Capture groups are a set of parentheses that allow you to reference a matched pattern later. In this case, there are three sets of parentheses, so you have three different groups you can reference. If you need the numbers without the symbols next to them, then simply move those symbols outside of their respective capture groups. I encourage you to take a greater look at regular expressions in general as they typically make these pattern-matching problems a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex for this problem.

If you have a minute I will fiddle something for the different things you want to fetch.

```
$str = 'Terms of Service ID: #928374 (Val: $2.50, Add\'l fee: 10.25%)';
$id = preg_match('/#[0-9]*/', $str, $matches)[0];
$val = preg_match(/\$[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/, $str, $matches)[0];
```